# File Migration Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

We are planning to integrate with google drive to do file uploads and downloads. On top of that we need to migrate 100 GB of files from our server to Drive. I was thinking about a job that continuously runs will move the files over. I was wondering what sort of limits (Frequency of API calls) they have in doing such a big transaction?

Comment: Hey @PSH, when writing a question take into account that a more direct answer is to be provided. Your question is very complex and can be divided into several others in order to get a swift and accurate response(s).
I would suggest to split the question and link then together.
As for your last question you can check this link [Google API Limits](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/request-frequency)

Answer (score 0):

Google drive does have a quota as far as how fast you can make calls to it

[image]

There is also a download limit that i have hit a few times but its undocumented and i have been unable to nail down exactly what it is

Comment: Have you seen any limits in regards to size of files that can be uploaded in certain time duration?

Comment: I have heard that It is possible to upload a 5 TB file.  I haven't personally tried as i dont have a single file thats that big.  On google drive a user has a limit to upload 750 gig a day this may give you a general idea of where the api limit may be per user